# Capturar evento "Save work item" no TFS - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Bom dia pessoal. Tudo bem?

Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 2015 para acessar os Work Items do TFS e estou procurando uma ferramenta que armazene algumas informações especificas das atividades em uma planilha Excel e, ao finalizar um Work Item, envie um e-mail com formatação específica para alguns destinatários.

Dei uma pesquisada e vi que as configurações do TFS dão suporte para o envio de e-mail, isso só tem que ser configurado... Porém não achei nada que atenda a questão da planilha, então pensei em desenvolver um add-in que faça as duas coisas!
Alguém saberia me indicar alguma ferramenta que tenha essas funcionalidades ou o que eu poderia pesquisar para começas a desenvolver a minha própria?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de armazenar informações específicas das atividades em uma planilha Excel, por que não armazenar nos próprios Work Items?

É possível customizá-los para adicionar campos e até mesmo alterar o workflow. Então é só disparar o envio de um email baseado nas informações. Você pode utilizar os web hooks e integrações, como você está em uma versão antiga, recomendo fazer o update para o 2018 Update 2 e utilizar várias features novas.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instalar o "TFS Office Integration Installer":

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=626605

2) No excel você pode se conectar em uma consulta do TFS:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]